# Bracket Notation - Accessing numeric keys without quotes

Tags: javascript, object

Can you guys give me some technical explanation why we can access object properties using Bracket Notation, **without** quotes? Using numeric keys, but the JavaScript does convert every key to **string**, right?

Example:

```
const people = {
  1 : {
    name: 'Ronaldo Fenômeno',
    age: 42
  },
  2 : {
    name: 'Ayrton Senna',
    age: 58
  },
  test : {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 123
  }
}
console.log(people[1]['name']) // why?
console.log(people['2'].name)
console.log(people['test']['name'])
```

Comment: because keys of an object are string and it converts it to a string. `typeof Object.keys({1:1})[0]` and when you access it applies toString(). See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names

Comment: Oh, I see now... thank you @epascarello!